# Oracle - Grant access to use tables of one schema in another schema

Tags: oracle12c

I have tables in **Schema A**. I created procedure in a package in **Schema B** for query data from the table in schema A as below:

```
PROCEDURE GET_DATAFROM_A (....)
AS BEGIN 
execute immediate ' GRANT SELECT ON '||A||'.'||tblname||' TO B';
open PO_Cursor for 'select * from '||A||'.'||tblname;
```

but when I execute the procedure it shows

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Did I have something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting as Schema B, you can't just say "grant myself access to tables in Schema A."

You're getting the `ORA-00942` because right now you have no privileges on the table yet so the grant is saying "I don't even know what table you're talking about."

But even if SchemaB could see the table, Oracle would then inform you that:

```
ORA-01749: you may not GRANT/REVOKE privileges to/from yourself
```

You'll need another user (like SchemaA) to grant the necessary privileges on the table to SchemaB.